# How to use part of image as button background in android?

Tags: android, button, png, android-framelayout

I have an .png image where i have formed some buttons in one image . now i want to use those figure on one drawing as background for different button. I am working on frame layout. How to proceed?
[image: In this image i want to use all figures for different button. Like first image (5,50) and size 40,25 will be used for first image]

Comment: Show screenshots of what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button is the child of your FrameLayout, add this to your FrameLayout in xml.

```
    android:background="@drawable/your_png"
```